Athena DynamoDB connector timeout
Since the Athena DynamoDB connector (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connectors-dynamodb.html)  is based on Lambda, does the Lambda time limitation affect executing the query?
What happens if a query lasts more than 15 minutes? Are there any alternatives or workarounds?

The connector calculates the number of of segments it needs to run a parallel scan, meaning that a single Lambda is not responsible for obtaining all the data, just a segment. The results are stored on S3 and then combined before being returned to Athena.
